# Invariance coding for running a latent growth model running under partial (scalar or metric) invariance

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, curve-fitting, invariance

I am running a second-order latent growth curve with 7 time points.

The model has a four indicator latent variables at the measurement level so I ran a longitudinal invariance test.
The model holds for partial scalar invariance, so I assume I can move on to a latent growth model.

So here is my question.

When I am coding the latent growth model I would code for invariance, labeling
the loadings and item intercepts to be equal across time. But if I had only partial invariance, **shouldn't the loadings or item intercepts that needed to be freed in the invariance test also need to be freed in the latent growth curve?**
I would really be grateful if somebody could also point to me to some readings which I can read up on this.

Comment: Yes, they would. The latent growth curve adds some more constraints, so your model needs to be correct before you add those constraints.

Comment: Thank you for responding! So in that case, if there are non-invariant item intercepts in the scalar invariance test, the item intercept for that item will also be freely estimated in the SO-GCM, right? If I am running the SO-GCM with a marker variable approach the marker indicator loading need to be fixed to 1 and intercepts to 0, so is it correct in regarding that it would not be appropriate to make any indicator that showed non-invariance (metric or scalar) the marker indicator?